# URL won't load inside iFrame

Tags: iframe, embed

I'm using myRealPage to create Mobile links for me. In the settings it creates links for various things like listings etc... I can embed all the links but one into an iFrame. All the others work perfectly fine but this one

http://listings.myrealpage.com/wps/recip/25064/m.form

It just sits there and tried to load. I do get one error saying this

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://listings.myrealpage.com" from accessing a frame with origin "MYSITE". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I'm not really understanding that because all the other links contain the same listings.myrealpage in them and work fine.

The code I have for the iFrame is this

```
<iframe src="LINK" name="frame2" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" height="800px" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

That's the same too for all the others but replacing the src part with the other links.

Hopefully there's an answer for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That error message is due to the **same-origin-policy**

Usually, this is sent in a **HTTP header** and causes the browser to deny a load of **IFRAME** content unless there's an exact match of port, protocol and domain.

E.g. port - usually 443 for SSL, or 80 if standard HTTP - protocol (http for parent page and iframe, or https for both) and domain (blah.domain.com and blah2.domain.com would be a *non-match*)

Either remove the restriction of the same-origin-policy (you may not be able to do this if you do not govern the server), or, satisfy it. Then, you'll be able to render that content within a frame.

You could use something like Fiddler to determine the erroneous url (It's free to download from Telerik) and where the request occurs.